# Compact design - building from off-the-shelf components

Tags: servomotor

I want to build a small cylindrical arm, with a main 360º angular servo on the longitudinal axis, and a secondary angular servo with variable speed in a trasversal axis that rotates with the main angular one. The secondary needs to receive data and power from a slip ring across the main servo, since it must be able to rotate freely and must not be binded by wirings. The width of the cylindrical arm must be below 0.4 cm

I've reviewed the market for off-the-shelf servos and there are a few that could fit the bill for the main servo, I know where to obtain the slip ring required, but it beats me where to obtain the secondary servo, since the space limitations demand that it is really small (< 0.2 cm) and the smallest I've been able to find on internet are 0.5 cm

Any suggestions are greatly welcome!

Comment: What are the real dimensions you're limited to? I'm surprised you found a 5mm wide servo (rather than one with a 5mm diameter arm), let alone a 2mm wide one.

Comment: If you can't find a motor that fits in that location, you might consider putting a motor closer to the base and using some sort of [cables](http://forums.trossenrobotics.com/robots.php?project_id=38) or [belts](http://harmonicdrive.net/reference/applicationhandbook/display.php?id=sce_whrpa) or (coaxial?) [rotating shafts](http://www.soleillapierre.ca/projects/lego/arm2/index.php) transfer the motion from the motor to the moving part.

Comment: a few tiny motors: ["How small can I make my robot tree?"](http://letsmakerobots.com/content/how-small-can-i-make-my-robot-tree-stepper-motor-vs-regular-servo); ["Tiny Pager Motor (TPM2)"](http://solarbotics.com/product/tpm2/); ["Tiny DC Motors"](http://www.hobbyengineering.com/CatMTINY.html); ["SQUIGGLE micro motor"](http://www.newscaletech.com/technology/squiggle-motors.php); etc.